# Strange offset in the CSS element position after changing orientation on iPad

Tags: css, ipad

I have a web page developed for an iPad for which I used different CSS files for different orientations:

```
<link REL="stylesheet" href="portrait_style.css" media="all  and (orientation:portrait)"/>
<link REL="stylesheet" href="landscape_style.css" media="all  and (orientation:landscape)"/>
```

When I start from landscape mode and then move to the portrait, I have to add 125px to all absolutely positioned elements. And when I start from portrait it is started from 0.

When I move from portrait to landscape and back, it again needs the offset.

There is a demo of this available [here](http://zeroowl.homelinux.net/modelity/asianout-demo/)

I suspect the problem is that there some landscape element that is not changed in portrait mode.

In chrome on my PC this is not happening.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the fixed position again with media queries:

```
/* portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    .[your-selector]{
        position:fixed;
    }
}
/* landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    .[your-selector]{
        position:fixed;
    }
}
```

It looks like when you set the property again it repaints it.

Comment: Solved it for me! Thanks. But I had to use `position: relative`

Comment: You don't have to repeat position: fixed, as long as you add these two orientation-specific blocks, the element will be repainted. This is just a good example :)

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by an element that pushes the boundaries of the browser viewport, either with a width over 100% or a left set to a negative value.

A fix I have found is to set the overflow of the body to make the viewport behave:

```
body {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Setting the `position` of the body will encapsulate all elements (whether absolute or relative) into the body and clip them at the edge of the body.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

in your `<head>` section.

More info: [Determining iPhone orientation using CSS](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/iphone-orientation-css)

Comment: Thanks , but I already have the      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>