# Absolute elements offset in landscape orientation

Tags: html, css, mobile

My page when viewed on a mobile browser (tested on Android JB and iOS 6) renders fine when initially loaded in both portrait and landscape modes. However, when I go **from landscape to portrait** the absolute positioned divs are offset from where they should actually be. The weird part is that if I am zoomed in when I change the orientation this problem doesn't manifest.

This is same as the problem mentioned here: [Strange offset in the CSS element position after changing orientation on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254774/strange-offset-in-the-css-element-position-after-changing-orientation-on-ipad) 
only difference being I am testing on a phone. I tried the solutions provided there but they don't seem to work.

Here is my CSS

```
       html{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        body{
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: #000;
        }

        #container{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-width: 960px;
            min-height: 544px;
        }

        #pic{
            display: table;
            height: 100%;
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            z-index: 5;
        }

        #links{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            bottom: 5px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 9;
            background: #ccc;
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)";
            filter: alpha(opacity=10);
            -moz-opacity: 0.1;
            -khtml-opacity: 0.1;                  
            opacity: 0.1;
        }

        #wrapper{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            bottom: 5px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 12;
        }

        #content{
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #content div{
            display: inline-block;
            *display: inline;
            zoom: 1;
            width: 20%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #content div *{
            vertical-align: middle;
            border: 0;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        /* portrait */
        @media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
            #container{
                position:relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-width: 960px;
            min-height: 544px;
            }
        }
        /* landscape */
        @media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
            #container{
                position:relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-width: 960px;
            min-height: 544px;
            }
        }
```

As you can see I have tried the solution from the other question which doesn't work. And my HTML structure

```
<div id="container">
        <img src="pic_jj.jpg" alt="image" id="pic" />
        <div id="links">

        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">

                <div>
                </div>

                <div>
                </div>

                <div>
                </div>

                <div>
                </div>

                <div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can view my page [here](http://jeevanjose.com) if you need a live demo. I should probably mention that I am looking for a non-js solution.

PS. I am using this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no;">
```

**Update** Screenshots.

> Here is what the initial load looks like (normal behaviour)
>   [image]
>
> Here's what happens when I change the orientation **from landscape to portrait**
>   [image]
>   [image]

Comment: Can you please provide screenshots of the current and expected results? This will help greatly in find a solution.

Comment: Like I explained, it loads up well initially. If you visit the page on a mobile change the orientation to landscape and then to portrait, you'll see that the bottom div is offset.

Comment: I've visited the site and messed around with it and I still don't understand what you're saying. I see no difference when making the orientation change. That is why I requested the screenshots.

Comment: @BigMacAttack I've added screenshots.

Comment: Thanks Jeevan. I was testing on an iPad running iOS 6.1.3 and this rendering issue doesn't occur for me. However a different issue is occurring: the page is rendered larger than the viewport, forcing me to scroll in both the x and y directions to see the entire background and bottom bar.

Comment: Why is your `#links` element empty? Do you mean to put the `#wrapper` element inside of it?

Comment: It's probably the nasty WebKit repaint problem showing up. Unfortunately, can't help you for the `looking for a non-js solution`. If you want the js solution, let me know.

Comment: I would approach the problem in a different way. 1st: there's a lot of unnecessary style on your stylesheet, since they are default values (no harm there, but they add noise and perhaps confusion). 2nd: use an image a div's background instead of using an `img` tag. 3rd: get rid of all those `display:table`, you don't need them. When working with absolute positioned elements, think of the normal flow of the document and how elements are clearing. My guess is that the CSS/markup is flawed but somehow working on first render. Changing orientation is actually a way to find such flaws...

Comment: I agree with Wallace. You should look to simplify your markup and make this easier (and faster) for the browser to render. You have empty elements and wrapper elements that don't need to be there. Also, the media queries in your CSS are unnecessary (especially considering they don't actually change anything).

Comment: @BigMacAttack The #links is supposed to be empty. There are tow divs in that bottom bar and #links is one of them. It's job is to provide that transparency that you see. I agree that I don't need the media queries. I just put that in to show that I tried the solution from that other answer. The initial view is because of the meta tag, again something that wasn't there initially but was put in to try to fix the problem.

Comment: @WallaceSidhrée The reason I did not use background image and used an img instead is to make it look the way it does. All of the background is not black, I have a black border around my img so that it 'blends' with the rest of the page which has a black background. This way no matter how wide/tall the viewer's screen is you always get that same visual effect. I have repeated the defaults because sometimes different browsers have different defaults plus I provide a lot of the sizes in percentages so it's better to explicitly specify percentage widths and heights from the root element.

Comment: @WallaceSidhrée  The display table was added because for some reason the content wasn't centering. I would be happy to remove it though. Please note that although it's live it's still a work in progress. The main hurdle I face is this question.

Comment: I don't know if I would worry about it on mobile, it's a hair tearing experience to try and make a PERFECT mobile site. Just advice

Comment: @brandonjordan I hear you mate. But this has been really annoying my. Have to find a solution.:)

Comment: Why not apply the transparency via a `background-color` property with an alpha value on the `#container` rather than as a `opacity` property on a separate element? Try `background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.1);`.

Comment: @BigMacAttack Because of browser support problems for rgba.

Comment: RGBa is supported in all major browsers except IE6-8, and you could support these browsers with a conditional statement + your ms `filter`. I wouldn't compromise your HTML markup just to support these dying browsers.

Comment: For fallback just declare `background-color:#000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);` For those who don't understand rgba, they will mark the bgc with it as invalid and use the previous (full color).

Comment: Guys thanks for the suggestions, appreciate it. But the real question is not being answered here.

Comment: I think what we are all indirectly trying to tell you here, is that we are not surprised that your page renders incorrectly. Your choice of markup and css is rather peculiar. There is no "quick fix" for this problem. But...taking the time to cleanup your html and styling (via a more traditional approach) should fix the issue for you.

Comment: @BigMacAttack Can you tell me what exactly comes off as 'peculiar', ignoring the blank div.

Comment: I got a very similar problem on nexus 10 tablet today. But when I changed my element's `position: abosulte` to `position: fixed` it works. Try it.

Comment: There are too many things to mention as a comment, so I'll formulate it in an answer. But here is one example: Why are you applying `zoom: 1;` to your flair wrapper elements?

Comment: @WallaceSidhrée I incorporated a few of your suggestions into my answer. I'm no longer seeing any rendering bugs on orientation change.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a live "fiddle" demo. Let me know if you still experience the rendering quirk with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by myself and Wallace Sidhrée in the comments above, you should approach this rendering problem differently by utilizing more traditional practices. Addressing these problems are likely to make your rendering quirk null and void. If not, it will at least make it drastically easier to find the problem. Here are a few things to look at:

-You have duplicate styles in your stylesheet (i.e. the unnecessary @media queries)
*You mention that you added these media-queries to show that you've tried a solution from a different SO question, but even if it were to work its the wrong approach to fix the problem because the results are likely to be undefined. In theory, the additional media-queries should not change the layout at all.*

-You're using an `<img>` tag to display a background, rather than the more traditional `background` property on a `<div>` element
 
*To achieve the blending with the black background that you desire, you should use both a background image and a color. Try: `background-color: #000000;` with `background-image: url(image.jpg)`. The background image is always stacked on top of the background color.*

-You are applying `display: table;` to your `#pic` element to try and achieve image centering
*You should be centering a background image by using `background-position: center;`*

-You use the `z-index` property on your `#pic` element without an accompanying position property setting
*Using z-index requires that the position property be set to either `fixed`, `absolute`, or `relative`. z-index has no affect on `position: static;` elements, which is the default value if not explicitly defined.*

-You are attempting to achieve background transparency by changing the opacity property of a separate element rather than as a background color setting on an element
*You mention you've done this because of the lack of support for rgba values. But the more traditional approach is to do what RaphaelDDL proposed and provide a fallback value that doesn't include alpha transparency.*

I'd recommend simplifying your HTML. It really should't take any more markup than this:

```
<body>
    <div id="image></div>
    <div id="flair">
        <div id="flair-container">
            <div class="flair"></div>
            <div class="flair"></div>
            <div class="flair"></div>
            <div class="flair"></div>
            <div class="flair"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a [**"FIDDLE"**](http://jsbin.com/iKUSAxU/2) that takes into account my suggestions. I'm not noticing any rotation quirks when testing on an iPad (iOS 6.1.3) and Nexus 7 (Android 4.2.2).

Comment: This works perfectly well. I should add that a lot of what you saw in the markup I had was work in progress. So the media queries etc. were to be removed later. I have put your code here: jeevanjose.com/3.html. If you were to open up this in IE7 or below you'll see that the page gets messed up. If you open up the page I have in the same browser different things get messed up. I guess the bottom line is there is no one size fits all solution specially when it comes to IE. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JeevanJose [Here](http://jsbin.com/iKUSAxU/4) is a demo that adds some IE fallback CSS. It adds a `-ms-filter` for the background image, a `filter` for the flair transparent background, a `*display: inline;` for the flair layout, and removes the blue borders on the anchors via `.fair-wrapper img { border: none; }`. It won't make your site look *identical* for the older versions of IE, but I do believe it helps it render more like one would expect. The good thing to keep in mind is that the total combined worldwide market share for IE5.5-IE8 is <5%.

Answer (score 1):

See I designed this and found it responsive to resizing of the browser. I require you to change the codes and test them in an I pad or a tab if possible. Please try I guess it will lead to a final result. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Jeevan Jose

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no;">
    <meta name="description" content="Jeevan Jose | About | Twitter | LinkedIn | Facebook | Email">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Computer Engineer, Software Engineer, IT, Jeevan Jose, Jeevan, Photographer">
    <meta name="author" content="Jeevan Jose">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <style type="text/css">
        html{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        body{
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: #000;
        }

        #container{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 90%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 90%;
        }

        #pic{
            display: table;
            height: 80%;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            z-index: 5;
        }

        #links{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%;
            bottom: 5px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 9;
            background: #ccc;
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)";
            filter: alpha(opacity=10);
            -moz-opacity: 0.1;
            -khtml-opacity: 0.1;                  
            opacity: 0.1;
        }

        #wrapper{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%;
            bottom: 5px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 12;
        }

        #content{
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #content div{
            display: inline-block;
            *display: inline;
            zoom: 1;
            width: 19%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #content div *{
            vertical-align: middle;
            border: 0;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        /* portrait */
        @media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
            #container{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 90%;
        }

        #pic{
            display: table;
            height: 80%;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            z-index: 5;
        }

        #links{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%;
            bottom: 5px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 9;
            background: #ccc;
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)";
            filter: alpha(opacity=10);
            -moz-opacity: 0.1;
            -khtml-opacity: 0.1;                  
            opacity: 0.1;
        }

        #wrapper{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%;
            bottom: 5px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 12;
        }
        }
        /* landscape */
        @media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
            #container{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 90%;
        }

        #pic{
            display: table;
            height: 80%;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            z-index: 5;
        }

        #links{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%;
            bottom: 5px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 9;
            background: #ccc;
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)";
            filter: alpha(opacity=10);
            -moz-opacity: 0.1;
            -khtml-opacity: 0.1;                  
            opacity: 0.1;
        }

        #wrapper{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%;
            bottom: 5px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 12;
        }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <img src="http://jeevanjose.com/pic_jj.jpg" alt="image" id="pic" />
        <div id="links">

        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">

                <div>
                <!--Facebook Button-->
                <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/follow.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fjosejeevan&amp;width=200&amp;height=21&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
                </div>

                <div>
                <!--Twitter handle-->
                <a href="https://twitter.com/jeevan_jose" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow @jeevan_jose</a>
                <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
                </div>

                <div>
                <!--LinkedIn badge-->
                <a href="http://uk.linkedin.com/in/josejeevan">      
                    <img src="http://www.linkedin.com/img/webpromo/btn_myprofile_160x33.png" width="160" height="33" border="0" alt="View Jeevan Jose's profile on LinkedIn">
                </a>
                </div>

                <div>
                <!--Stackoverflow Flair-->
                <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2025666/jeevan-jose">
                    <img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2025666.png?theme=dark" width="208" height="50" alt="SO Flair">
                </a>
                </div>

                <div>
                <!--Email Button-->
                <a href="mailto:contact@jeevanjose.com?subject=Reference%20-%20jeevanjose.com">
                    <img src="email_button.png" alt="email button" />
                </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Start of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var sc_project=8629786; 
    var sc_invisible=1; 
    var sc_security="d00c7885"; 
    var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
    "https://secure." : "http://www.");
    document.write("<sc"+"ript type='text/javascript' src='" +
    scJsHost+
    "statcounter.com/counter/counter_xhtml.js'></"+"script>");
    //]]>
    </script>
    <noscript><div class="statcounter"><a title="web statistics"
    href="http://statcounter.com/free-web-stats/"
    class="statcounter"><img class="statcounter"
    src="http://c.statcounter.com/8629786/0/d00c7885/1/"
    alt="web statistics" /></a></div></noscript>
    <!-- End of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->

    <!--Google Analytics-->
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-43825613-1', 'jeevanjose.com');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
</body>
```

Some images might not be visible due to the path problem as I did the changes in notepad but do check please. :)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. You can view the page here `http://jeevanjose.com/1.html`. But thanks for taking the time to focus on the actual problem.

Comment: I saw that on my samsung Note . Looks wierd. I guess the styling is correct but some thing needs to be done to apply them when in tablet devices . Ill give it few more try and update the code accordingly. Tell me if you find success

Comment: and also let me know one more thing. I guess if you open the app in the landscape mde then it is fine even if you go t potrait then to landscape it is not getting distorted. When i tested in Note 8 it was please share your observation.

Comment: I have edited the code give a try. and also share the link would be use ful in debugging from here :)

Comment: It does work. It messes up other  styling but it solves the fundamental problem. `www.jeevanjose.com/2.html` So what you are doing is you are reapplying the styles on orientation change, right?

Comment: happy to know at least it workd :) actually both modes need to have seprate styling :) I was looking forward to your reply as entire day I spent coding in note pad. Lo lets move to the serious part apart from the happy part. What I did was just apply style for the different orientation as both has to be kept in mind as well as a global style. and everything in % . the other styles also need to be in the orientation styles as Making A Responsive design in this era is our duty So Y take risk :D :D :)

Comment: I have crossed my thresh hold of getting upvotes for today :)