# How do I convert the html of a website popup into a mobile compatible site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ios, css

I've got a popup what appears on my website with the following code, it uses the async-twitter library to connect/authorize with twitter.

How can I turn the following code into a mobile compatible site so it does the following:

1) Works with Safari on iOS (Apple Devices)

2) Is centered on mobile devices instead of being off center...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=[twitter-apikey]&v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--STYLE-->
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color: #10661A; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#logo {background-image:url(\'img/logo.png\'); width: 770px; height: 104px;  }
#content { background-color:#FFF; width: 770px; hddeight: 334px; }
.connect { width: 249px; height:49px; display:block; background:transparent url(\'img/button.png\') center top no-repeat; }
.connect:hover { background-image: url(\'img/buttonhover.png\'); }
.title { color: #1c1c1c; padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0px; }
.tweet { padding: 7px 100px; font-size:13px; line-height:19px; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px; text-align:left; color: #343434; background-color: #eeeeee; border: 1px solid #e0e0e0; }
.link { font-style:italic; font-size:13px; line-height:19px; color: #197da4; }
.link2 { font-size:11px; text-decoration:underline; line-height:19px; color: #c2eeff; }
.account { font-weight: bold; font-size:14px; line-height:19px;  margin: 0 20px 10px 20px; padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px; text-align:center; color: #3e3e3e; background-color: #eeeeee; border: 1px solid #e0e0e0; }
.button { background-image:url(\'img/button.png\'); background-repeat:no-repeat;  color:#FFF; font-size:16px; text-decoration:none;  padding: 5px 33px 5px 33px; font-weight: bold; width: 284px; }
.ads { font-size:11px; text-align:center; color:#FFF; margin-top: 25px; }
.p1 { font-size: 13px; color: #7f7f7f; text-align:center; margin: 0px; padding-top: 10px; line-height: 18px; }
.line-separator{height:1px; border-bottom:1px solid #c8dbe3; width: 730px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px; }
</style>
<!--END STYLE-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>[title]</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    twttr.anywhere(function (T) {
        T("#tweet").linkifyUsers();
        T("#account").linkifyUsers();
        T.hovercards();
    });
</script>

<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="content">
        <p class="p1">Stuff here... Stuff here... Stuff here... Stuff here... </p>
        <p class="p1">Stuff here... Stuff here... Stuff here... Stuff here...</p>
        <div class="line-separator"></div>
        <p class="title">Stuff here... Stuff here... Stuff here... Stuff here... </p>
        <center><a href="[twitter-authorization-url]" class="connect" title="Click to authorize with twitter"></a></a></center>
</div>
<p class="ads">Copyright &copy; 2013 <a href="http://website.com/" class="link2">website</a>. All Rights Reserved.</<p> 
</body>
</html>
```

I would greatly appreciate any help possible.

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Comment: You can try handheld-device css. like this: @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
    /*--- iPhone only CSS here ---*/
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Try coding in the css in Percentage

Here a tutorial : [percentage in css](http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/)

2 - For mobile devices add css - go through my answer over there.

[coding for mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658550/absolute-elements-offset-in-landscape-orientation/18771728?noredirect=1#comment27728421_18771728)

3 - For different modes maintain two styling apart from a global styling

```
/* landscape */ @media screen and (orientation:landscape) 
@media screen and (orientation:portrait)
```

Try you will get a very responsive design :)